# How do I add/remove classes on some of my tags when I scroll over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have quite a few hover animations on my website but it doesn't really have the same effect on mobile (because users doesn't hover on mobile). So I want to add all the :hover effects to different classes and add that class to my objects when a user scrolls over it. (I assume I will be using media queries so that it only adds the class when its mobile view)

Here is an example of code that I would like to add the scroll effect:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div id="test" class="about-me col-6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="image col-6">
        <img src="../assets/test.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>

.about-me{
    color: white;
}

.about-me:hover{
    color: black;
    transition: color 1s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .about-me-mobile:{
        color: black;
        transition: color 1s ease;
    }
}
```

I want to add ".about-me-mobile" when a user scrolls over the about me section.

I have tried the example on stackoverflow.com/a/488073/7724517 but I am getting no output or errors.

Comment: this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/7724517

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)